# Error handling with Get-wmiObject for pscustomobject in Powershell

Tags: powershell, null, pscustomobject

Building this script I want to have the output stored in a TXT file and leave the details blank which cannot be found.
It works for the Get-ADuser function but not for Get-wmiObject.
I've got my PC names and user ids from a CSV file but sometimes a user doesn't have a PC or the workstation is not turned on so I get no output. Then I want to leave those details blank.
I've tried with try and catch but it seems not working. Any advice?

> 

```
$userName1 = "UserX"
$Computernames = Import-CSV 'C:\PCnames.csv' -Delimiter ';'
$pcName = $Computernames.Where({ $_."User ID" -match $userName1})."PC Name"

$aProperties = @(
        'Name'
        'mail'
        'OfficePhone'
        'Description'
        'PasswordLastSet'
        'LastBadPasswordAttempt'
        'LockedOut'
        'Enabled'
        'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed'
    )
    $aUser = Get-Aduser -Identity $userName1 -Properties $aProperties
    $aUser


$IP = try {Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computername $pcName -ea stop |
        Where { $_.IPAddress } |
        Select -Expand IPAddress | 
        Where { $_ -like '10.33*' -or $_ -like '10.44*'} } 
catch {""}

$Model = try { (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $pcName -ea stop ).Model}
catch {""}

$OS =try { Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -Computername $pcName -ea stop | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}}

catch{""}





[pscustomobject]@{   UserID                      = $aUser.Name
                     Mail                        = $aUser.mail
                     Phone                       = $aUser.OfficePhone
                     Hostname                    = $pcName
                     LockedStatus                = $aUser.LockedOut
                     AccountEnabled              = $aUser.Enabled
                     LastBadPasswordAttempt      = $aUser.LastBadPasswordAttempt
                     OSVersion                   = $OSVersion.Version
                     OSName                      = $OSVersion.Name
                     IPAddress                   = $IP
                     Model                       = $Model }
```

Comment: While it should work, using `-EA Stop` with `try/catch` for single commands like this, is superfluous. Normally you would pass `-EA Ignore` or `-EA SilentlyContinue`, which produces an empty output in case of an error and you don't need to `catch`.

Comment: I have tried removing the try and catch and try with SIlentlyContinue and Ignore, it doesn't help..

Comment: What is the outcome? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
+ ... t-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $pcName -ea ign

Comment: The problem is that the workstation needs to be turned on and the user must have a workstation otherwise the script is not functioning. It cannot be solved by try/catch, -ea stop, ignore, silently continue.. Tried all of this...